# How to sleep a process when using multiprocessing in Python 3.8.10 without using time.sleep()

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using around 1500 process multiprocessing.pool to run tasks parallely.

In every process I need to perform a funtion every 5 mins, i.e every 5 mins I need to read 1500 files simultaneously.For every thread I am using time.sleep(300 - start_time) at the end of execution of function. However when trying to sleep only 16 process are executed because of 16 cores in my PC, rest all processes are not working.

below is the code:

```
import logging
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
from scipy.stats import linregress
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method, Pool, Value
import multiprocessing as mp
import traceback
import atr_bb as ab
import numpy as np
from operator import getitem
import datetime as dt
import time
import api as sa
import requests

def init(args):
    ''' store the counter for later use '''
    global counter
    counter = args


def train(string, dones, left_after):
    global counter

    count=0
    t0 = dt.datetime.now()
    time.sleep(300.0 - (t0.minute%5*60 + t0.second))
    
    while(True):
        count+=1
        t0 = dt.datetime.now()
        if(t0.hour>20):
            return
        
        print(string, " ", count)
        func(string)# function to be performed
        time.sleep(300.0 - (t0.minute%5*60 + t0.second) + 10)

        except:
            traceback.print_exc()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = pd.read_csv('data.csv')['A']
    counter = Value('i', 0)
    mp.freeze_support()
    mp_manager = mp.Manager()
    data_dict = mp_manager.dict()
    dones = mp_manager.list()
    left = mp_manager.list()
    args = []
    for string in l:
        args.append((str(string), dones, left))
    
    p = Pool(initializer = init, initargs = (counter, ))
    p.starmap(train, args)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Now how can I pause a process for some time and CPU can be utilized by other processes?It seems time.sleep() is still using CPU and other strings are not processed totally.

As per the answer2 posted by BooBoo, I have tried below code can you please suggest if it can be made faster.

```
import os
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
import logging
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
from multiprocessing import Process, set_start_method, Pool, Value
import multiprocessing as mp
import traceback
import atr_bb as ab
import numpy as np
from operator import getitem
import datetime as dt
import time
import stock_api as sa
import requests
import asyncio
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Manager
import sys

SLEEP_TIME = 5 * 60 # 5 minutes

async def train(x, lock):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    """
    # I/O-bound portion:
    import aiofiles
    async with aiofiles.open(x, mode='r') as f:
        data = await f.read()
    # CPU-bound portion:
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, data)
    """
    # but no I/O-bound portion for this demo:

    async with lock:
        data = get_data(x)
        
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, data, x)
    

def train_part2(data, x):
    """ CPU-intensive portion """
    print(x, " ", data.iloc[-1,-1]) # just print data

async def dispatcher(x, lock):
    while(True):
        t0 = dt.datetime.now()
        if(t0.hour>=15):
            return
        
        t1 = time.time()
        await train(x, lock)
        t2 = time.time()
        time_to_sleep = SLEEP_TIME - (t2 - t1)
        if time_to_sleep > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)

async def main():
    l = pd.read_csv('data.csv')['A']
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    t0 = dt.datetime.now()
    
    coroutines = ((dispatcher(x, lock)) for x in l)
    await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

    t1 = dt.datetime.now()
    
    print(t1-t0)
    
# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Might be a good idea to redesign specifically to keep your number of processes much closer to the number of cores, e.g. no more than 2x but preferably <16, rather than 100x as you have now. Quite surprised you even got it to run at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think Pool or the way you do this is the best approach. If you have a Pool, it will have N workers that can run in parallel. By default N is the number of your cores.  In your case the first thing a worker does is that it goes to sleep. It blocks the worker in the pool but it is not doing anything. You can try increasing the number of pool workers but you will most likely hit an OS limit of something if you try to launch 1500 workers.

My strong advice is to redesign your app so that you will do the sleeping and waiting somewhere else and only dispatch tasks to a Pool worker when the nap time is over. Not sure if it is suitable in your case, but you could combine threads and Pool. Make the napping happen in a thread and only dispatch a worker when there is work to be done, and remove all sleeps from your pool worker.

This is just a dummy snippet to demonstrate the idea but it runs.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import threading
from time import sleep


def worker(x):
    print(x)

def dispatcher(p, y):
    p.apply(worker, args=(y,))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool()
    for a in range(0,1500):
        threading.Timer(5, dispatcher, [p,a]).start()
    sleep(10)
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

In this script `worker()` is your `train()`. My worker does nothing else but spits out the sequence number to prove it works.  I have added a dispatcher that will be run in a timed thread. This will do the waiting and as soon as the wait time is over, it submits a task to the pool.

This will still block if your `train()` takes a long time to complete. You still have only a limited number of pool workers and if they are blocked by the actual work they do, then you are out of luck. You can try increasing your pool size a little but not to thousands. This will not block because you are just waiting for five minutes to pass as a thread does the waiting for you.

You can also use the dispatcher function to launch another Timer thread of itself as its final task if you just want to keep repeating the same tasks over and over.

Comment: I have tried a working solution where i execute new multipocessing pool every 5 mins..however let me try your solution and see which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have already accepted an answer. Nevertheless, I thought I would suggest another way using `asyncio` *coroutines*, which is probably more suitable than threading when creating such a large number (~15,000) of concurrent tasks. Also, I wanted to make explicit how you might do the timing so that the  repetitive operation (reading and processing a file in your case, printing a value in my example) would be done in a loop that executes once every 5 minutes.

The actual reading of the file, which is an I/O-bound "process", should be done using the `aiofiles` package from the `PyPI` repository as I have indicated in comments. Then the CPU-bound processing of what has been read should be done in a process pool, the facility for which is provided by `asyncio`:

```py
import asyncio
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Manager
import sys

SLEEP_TIME = 5 * 60 # 5 minutes

async def train(x):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    """
    # I/O-bound portion:
    import aiofiles
    async with aiofiles.open(x, mode='r') as f:
        data = await f.read()
    # CPU-bound portion:
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, data)
    """
    # but no I/O-bound portion for this demo:
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, x)

def train_part2(data):
    """ CPU-intensive portion """
    print(data) # just print data

async def dispatcher(x):
    while not terminate_flag.value:
        t1 = time.time()
        await train(x)
        t2 = time.time()
        time_to_sleep = SLEEP_TIME - (t2 - t1)
        if time_to_sleep > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)

async def main():
    coroutines = (dispatcher(x) for x in range(15000))
    await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

def handle_ctrl_c(signum, stack_frame):
    terminate_flag.value = 1

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        terminate_flag = manager.Value('i', 0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_ctrl_c) # terminate on ctrl-c
        asyncio.run(main())
```

**Update**

Here is how I would incorporate using coroutines with accessing a webserver and limiting fetching to a certain rate per second:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import time
import signal
from multiprocessing import Manager
import sys

# 10 requests per second (but for 15000 requests, this will take 25 minutes)
REQUESTS_PER_SECOND = 10
SLEEP_TIME = 5 * 60 # 5 minutes

requests_made_last_second = 1
time_of_first_request = None

async def train(session, x):
    global time_of_first_request, requests_made_last_second

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    # make sure we do not do more than the appropriate requests per second:
    if time_of_first_request is None:
        time_of_first_request = time.time()
    else:
        t = time.time()
        if t - time_of_first_request >= 1:
            # start of new second interval
            time_of_first_request = t
            requests_made_last_second = 1
        elif requests_made_last_second < REQUESTS_PER_SECOND:
            requests_made_last_second += 1
        else:
            # must wait for new second:
            # this will block all coroutines:
            time.sleep(time_of_first_request + 1 - t)


    """
    # I/O-bound portion:
    async with session.get(f'http://python.org?{x}') as response:
        data = await response.text()
    # CPU-bound portion:
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, data)
    """
    # but no I/O-bound portion for this demo:
    loop.run_in_executor(None, train_part2, x)

def train_part2(data):
    """ CPU-intensive portion """
    print(data) # just print data

async def dispatcher(x):
    while not terminate_flag.value:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            t1 = time.time()
            await train(session, x)
            t2 = time.time()
            time_to_sleep = SLEEP_TIME - (t2 - t1)
            if time_to_sleep > 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)

async def main():
    coroutines = (dispatcher(x) for x in range(15000))
    await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)

def handle_ctrl_c(signum, stack_frame):
    terminate_flag.value = 1

# Required for Windows:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Manager() as manager:
        terminate_flag = manager.Value('i', 0)
        signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handle_ctrl_c) # terminate on ctrl-c
        asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Actually I also want to get data from the server online for each of the string every 5 mins. Can you please let me know how can i change your code.  I am using counter.get_lock() while getting the data because i can extract data for 1 string only at a time from the server and then multiprocessing can process the data while other process reads data for another string.

Comment: simply, you can understand this as an activity monitor app which gets data for 1500 patients at a single time every 5 mins and process it, which can read data for 1 patient at a time.

Comment: Are you doing both file I/O *and* getting data from a server, the latter which must be "single threaded", or just getting data from a server and then processing it, which is CPU-intensive?

Comment: I need to read data from the server and then process it..Reading data from files was just a prototype

Comment: Then what you said in your question about reading 15000 files (or from a server) *simultaneously* was completely erroneous because now you are saying it has to be one-at-a-time. Don't you think that might make a big difference?

Comment: sorry for wrong info, actually I did not knew the api request limit is set to 10, I need to pay more for many requests per second..I think it is set to 10 requests per second...I have tried your solution with a lock and update in the question post...can you please help a check if above implemenetation can be made faster.

Comment: At 10 requests per second, it will take 15000 / 10 or 1500 seconds or 25 minutes to do one iteration. There is no way  therefore you can process your function every 5 minutes. How can I make my implementation faster given your limitations?